# React Apollo: apollo-cache-persist seems to not be working

Tags: apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

Maybe I misunderstood what this package does, but I assumed that it would read cached responses and help with offline application functionality.

```
import React from 'react'
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo'
import gql from 'graphql-tag'

export const DATA_QUERY = gql`
    query Data {
        me {
            name
            bestFriend {
                name
            }
        }
    }
`

const options = () => ({
  fetchPolicy: 'cache-only'
})

const withData = graphql(DATA_QUERY, { options })

export const Start = ({ data }) =>
    data.loading ? (
        'loading!'
    ) : data.me ? (
        <div>
      {console.log('data', data)}
            <h3>Me: {data.me.name}</h3>
            <p>Best friend: {data.me.bestFriend.name}</p>
        </div>
    ) : (
        'no data'
    )

export default withData(Start)

// index.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo'
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client'
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory'
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http'
import { persistCache } from 'apollo-cache-persist'

const cache = new InMemoryCache()

persistCache({
  cache,
  storage: window.localStorage,
  debug: true
})

export const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: new HttpLink({ uri: 'https://v9zqq45l3.lp.gql.zone/graphql' }),
  cache
})

ReactDOM.render(
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <App />
  </ApolloProvider>,
document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

I do have the cache in my localStorage

```
apollo-cache-persist: "{"$ROOT_QUERY.me":{"name":"Bob","bestFriend":{"type":"id","id`enter code here`":"$ROOT_QUERY.me.bestFriend","generated":true}"
```

When running the above example with fetchPolicy: 'cache-only' the component renders 'no data'. If I do the default fetchPolicy, cache-first, then I get the expected result but I can see the network request is being made.

EDIT: Now works with Daniels answer and this workaround waits for cache to be restored before running the query.

```
import Start from './Start'

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    show: false
  }

  toggle = () =>
    this.setState({ show: !this.state.show })

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <br/><br/>
        <button onClick={this.toggle}>Show it</button>
        <br/><br/>
        {this.state.show && <Start />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to correctly cache and later retrieve the data from the cache, Apollo needs an `id` (or `_id`) to work with. If you want to use a different property as the id (like `name`), you can pass a dataIdFromObject function to your configuration for the in-memory cache:

```
const cache = new InMemoryCache({
  dataIdFromObject: object => {
    switch (object.__typename) {
      //User is whatever type "me" query resolves to
      case 'User': return object.name;
      default: return object.id || object._id;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Daniel, thanks a ton. I totally spaced this and it helped me to get it to work. However, there does seem to be an issue where the cache is restored but not until the query is sent so it always fails. 

Check out my other code snippet, I just waited for the cache and then showed the component. 

Is there currently a way to make sure that the cache is restored before running any queries without having to do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this works, though I wonder if there should be a more elegant solution. Maybe the Retry Link.

https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-cache-persist/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+

```
export class Index extends Component {
    state = {
        client: null
    }

    async componentWillMount() {
        const httpLink = new HttpLink({ uri: 'https://v9zqq45l3.lp.gql.zone/graphql' })

        const link = ApolloLink.from([ httpLink ])

        const cache = new InMemoryCache({
            dataIdFromObject: (object) => {
                switch (object.__typename) {
                    // User is whatever type "me" query resolves to
                    case 'User':
                        return object.name
                    default:
                        return object.id || object._id
                }
            }
        })

        await persistCache({
            cache,
            storage: window.localStorage,
            debug: true
        })

        const client = new ApolloClient({
            link,
            cache
    })

    this.setState({ client })
    }

    render() {
        return !this.state.client ? (
            null
        ) : (
            <ApolloProvider client={this.state.client}>
                <App />
            </ApolloProvider>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Index />, document.getElementById('root'))
```